# Mysql import force insert

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this dump.sql.gz 1gig (around 6 extracted) where sadly, it contains some invalid geometries. The actual dump throws this `Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field`.

I could simply add `--force` option but it would actually skip those rows and not insert them. I can't afford to skip them because they are essential. They are linked to many other multiple tables through foreign key relations. Is there a way to tell mysql to simply ignore those invalid geometries errors and actually force the insert of offending rows so I can correct them after the import.

Opening the actual .sql file and manually correcting each bad row seems like the only way for now...

Any suggestions ?